# The Future of CSS3 Mobile Detection

Tags: mobile, css, mobile-website

Currently, front-end developers rely on CSS3 media queries (resolution detection) for targeting mobile devices. With the Galaxy Nexus and other new phones coming out at resolutions greater than 800x600 (1280x720 in the case of the G.N.), how will developers be able to **strictly** target  mobile devices with those resolutions, and not grandpa/grandma's aging desktop running Windows XP?

**EDIT:** It's becoming clear that what I'm looking for, in an ideal world, would be some additional API to specifically target a handheld/tablet device. The "handheld" media query exists, but considering neither Apple nor Android support this, it might as well be forgotten.

Given the great foresight HTML5 and CSS3 have shown recently, it puzzles me why this problem hasn't been given greater thought.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of mobile detection in CSS is to accomodate the usually lower resolution. If a mobile device has a bigger resolution, it's obviously perfectly capable of viewing a webpage like a normal computer. I believe that's the point of having bigger screens.

If you *need* detection, use JavaScript and load in stylesheets as needed.

Comment: The one caveat would be image size/weight. Even though the screen is capable, the network might not be.

Comment: Good point. Very good point, actually... I'm so used to optimizing my images losslessly to <1Kb that I forgot about this.

Comment: What happens when, 3 years from now, the majority of smartphones are greater than 800x600? Nobody will ever develop a mobile-optimized version of their website? Nonsense. That you think a 4-5" screen should see the same experience somebody on a 19" screen sees just because of similar screen resolution seems ridiculous. Without proper scaling, everything would be tiny, no?

Comment: Every mobile device I have is equipped with an easy way of zooming the page. Even the old DS from 2004 does this.

Comment: So then every mobile user is forced to zoom their page to be able to click that form submit button, or to click that next page link? Sounds like a terrible future to me.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution detection is not the only detection that media queries allow; you can target pixel density on devices too:

http://menacingcloud.com/?c=highPixelDensityDisplays

Many of the newer devices with higher resolutions will also be using higher pixel densities.

Comment: Desktop/laptop monitors have pixel density as well, so to try and find the line between the two may prove impossible or at the very least entirely too difficult.